# Can't connect to mongodb on remote but can on local

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect my `node.js` server (on ec2 instance) to my mongodb server (on ec2 instance but not the same). All works fine, i can connect to my mongodb with mongo on local but my `node.js` can't. Event if i try to type this command :

```
mongo <ec2-instance>/<dbname> -u <username> -p <password> --authenticationDatabase <dbname>
```

i get this error :

> E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server
>   :27017, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13 @(connect):1:6 exception:
>   connect failed

Comment: You probably need to open up incoming ports on your EC2 instance

Comment: Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: I don't think the problème come from here. Everything was working great but my mongodb server crashed (idk why) and won't start again. I made it work for a minute but it won't work again now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2018-02-15T10:37:08.017+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2888 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ip-172-31-23-145
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.017+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.9
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.017+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 876ebee8c7dd0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.017+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.017+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.017+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.017+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.017+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: amazon
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.017+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.017+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.017+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.017+0000 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.042+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.042+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.042+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.042+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.042+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.042+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3480M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.065+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1518691028:65354][2888:0x7f4adae46e00], file:collection-2--1305918998266443804.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: /data/db/collection-2--1305918998266443804.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.065+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status UnknownError: 1: Operation not permitted at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp 95
    2018-02-15T10:37:08.065+0000 I -        [initandlisten]

    ***aborting after invariant() failure


    2018-02-15T10:37:08.076+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
```

Here is what i got when i try to start mongod on my instance..